# How to send data after registration using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a simple registration form in laravel blade template, now after a user is registered I would like to send data to another service.

Here is what I have so far

Blade template

```
 <form method="POST" id="RegisterForm" action="{{ route('register') }}">
    @csrf

    <div>
        First Name
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{ old('first_name') }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        Last Name
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{ old('last_name') }}">
    </div>
    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>
    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password-confirm">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit" id='register' name="register" >register</button>
    </div>
</form>

@if (isset($_POST['register']))
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
<?php dd($first_name); ?> 

 $clientId = '*********';
 $apiKey = 'mykey'; 
 $apiSecret = '**********************'; 
 $endpoint = 'http://***.salesmanago.pl'
@endif
```

Now when I submit my form no errors no even var_dump data in console, what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Is that the `register.blade.php`? Personally I wouldn't handle this in a `view` blade template but in the controller. And btw, there is no `$_POST['register']` in your form, your button needs a `name` attribute for that to work. Scratch that, code has been edited. (But, you still have two fields named `password`)

Comment: `register` route needs to be there in `routes/web` file and for that route a function must be explained in some controller

Comment: There are no errors because your blade file does not contain anything to display errors. Read [Displaying The Validation Errors](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors)

Comment: @kerbholz Yes, I was thinking to add it in the controller  but I dont know how , I will add my controller though

Comment: @kerbholz I have added a controller can you help out?

Comment: See my last comment, I'd implement validation error display in your blade first to see any errors. Also as stated, two fields named `password`, fix this first. Also, your validation contains `agree_1` and `recaptcha_response` which are nowhere to be found in your form

Comment: Laravel offers pretty good scaffolding for user related stuff. Like login, logout and registration. I'd look at using that, If the case isn't about learning how to do this stuff in Laravel